# How to send an API-request to google via JsonObjectRequest?

Tags: android, google-api, http-post, google-vision, jsonobjectrequest

I'd like to test the cloud vision API in my Android application.

The API is activated and it works in the Google Cloud Explorer like the image below shows.

[image: Google APIs Explorer]

How can I make a simple post request by a RequestQueue-object?

I tried a lot of but my program always jumps in the `onErrorResponse` method.

my code:

```
private static String apiKey = "myAPIKey";
private static final String baseURI = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?fields=responses%2FfaceAnnotations&key=" + apiKey;


private static String exampleRequest = "{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageUri\":\"https://wikipedia.de/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2-de.svg\"}},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"TEXT_DETECTION\"}]}]}";



private static void testRequest(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = getJSONRequest(exampleRequest);
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener = getResponseListener();
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = getErrorListener();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(baseURIPost, jsonObject, responseListener, errorListener);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

private static Response.ErrorListener getErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    };
}

private static Response.Listener<JSONObject> getResponseListener() {
    return new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Object response) {
        }
    };
}

private static JSONObject getJSONRequest(String json) {
    try {
        return new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was no billing added to the API-key.
The code in the question above works fine now.